# Query parameters in request on Django 3.0.3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm putting together an API and need to add query parameters to the URI like `https://www.example.com/api/endpoint?search=term&limit=10`.

1. My first question is, in Django 3.0, I'd need to use [`re-path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path) to accomplish parsing out the various parameters, correct?
2. Secondly, the question is about convention. It seems like two of the three APIs I've been working with a lot lately us a convention like:

   ```
   /api/endpoint?paramater1=abc&parameter2=xyz
   ```

   Another uses something like:

   ```
   /api/endpoint?$parameter1=abc&parameter2=abc
   ```

   Looking at some past Django question related to this topic, I see stuff like:

   ```
   /api/endpoint/?parameter1=abc&parameter2=xyz
   ```

   Another post I read was suggesting that parameters should be separated with `;`.

   I guess I'm just curious what the "correct" convention should be either in terms of Django or general concensus.
3. Lastly, it seems to me what I'm trying to accomplish should be a `GET` request. The front-end sends the user defined parameters (`section` and `startingPage`) to the back-end where a PDF is generated matching those parameters. When it is generated, it sends it back to the FE. The PDFs are much too large to generate client-side. `GET` would be the correct method in the case, correct?

Comment: To number 1: that’s incorrect, query parameters are not used for url matching in Django, they can be accessed via request.GET in your views

Comment: Your question is tagged `django-rest-framework` but your examples are plain Django. DRF handles all your questions.

Comment: The part in `re_path` or `path` do *not* match the querystring, these only match, as the name suggests, the *path* of the URL, so the things *before* the `?`.

Comment: There is no "established convention". You specify the parameters together with the semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I elected to go with the first convetion:

```
/api/endpoint?paramater1=abc&parameter2=xyz
```

Simply because the majority of APIs I work with use this convention.

For my files:

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

from .views import GeneratePDFView

app_name = 'Results'

urlpatterns = [
    path('/endpoint',
         GeneratePDFView.as_view(), name='generate_pdf')
]
```

```
# view.py

from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class GeneratePDFView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(request.query_params) == 2:
            data['id'] = {'id': request.user.id}
            data['starting_page'] = request.query_params.get('parameter1')
            data['data_view'] = request.query_params.get('parameter2')
            serializer = GeneratePDFSerializer(data=data)
        ...
```